# How do I create a "quick post" bookmarklet for use with Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet. This is not working:

```
javascript:window.location="http://domain.com/node/add/content_type?title="+encodeURIComponent(document.title)
```

The [Prepopulate module](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) is not ported for D7. Any recommendations?

Comment: I think you need some more detail here on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box, Drupal 7 doesn't support form population from the URL. Just like Drupal 6. That's why the [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module exists. Prepopulate is about 100 LoC, porting it to Drupal 7 is probably the best option. The effort has been started, see issue [#935990](http://drupal.org/node/935990).

Answer (score 2):

As Pierre noted, the Prepopulate module is your way to go. I just installed it for Drupal 7 and it seems stable enough (works for the post title and body, anyway). The `USAGE.txt` that comes with it includes some info on using it for a bookmarklet for exactly this purpose.

However, I found that the code offered there didn't work for me: I had to change the variable name used for the body text from `edit[body_field][body]` to `edit[body][und][0][value]`. My guess is that this is because the site was previously upgraded from Drupal 6 to 7, but I can't say for sure.

Not to self-promote or anything, but I just published a long blog post about this, including the gotchas I found (like the variable name for the body field) and the version I wound up using: http://www.drupaldork.com/2011/08/mimicking-wordpress-press-bookmarklet-drupal-7

UPDATE September 11, 2011: I just released the [QuickPost Bookmarklet module](http://drupal.org/project/quickpost_bookmarklet) to add a frontend to make it easier to customize your bookmarklet. It requires Prepopulate, but it seems to be reasonably stable at this point—at least, for simple usage like this.